# Facebook login button not refreshing to logout automatically

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using 'Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK', I have a login button which works fine, i.e. user is logged in OK.(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#loginbutton).

However, the button does not change to the Logout button until I refresh the page. After refresh the logout button is displayed and when clicked reverts to  login button as expected. Following is the full code which can be run from within IIS. I put it in my default web site and called http://localhost/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/test.html.

NOTE: Add your App Id where it says, ADD YOUR APP ID HERE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row margin-bottom-small">
        <div id="login-button" class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></div>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                testAPI();
            }
        }
        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                                FB.init({
                                appId      : 'ADD YOUR APP ID HERE',
                                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                                xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                                version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
                            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        };
        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
        // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

FB code is from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#example

I don't want to refresh the page programatically. It is a single page application and refreshing the page will take me to the start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't refresh automatically - perhaps that by design. Here is my workaround - basically add the logout button and call FB.logout myself. If someone from Facebook dev team can provide a more elegant solution, I'd love to know. Thanks.

NOTE: Add your App Id where it says, ADD YOUR APP ID HERE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row margin-bottom-small">
        <div id="login-button" class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></div>
        <div hidden id="logout-button" class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" onlogin="logout();">Log Out</div>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                testAPI();
            } else {
                // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
                //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log into this app.';
                document.getElementById('login-button').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('logout-button').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }
        function logout() {
            FB.logout(function (response) {
                document.getElementById('logout-button').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('login-button').style.display = '';
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You have been logged out!';
            });
        }
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                                FB.init({
                                appId      : 'ADD YOUR APP ID HERE',
                                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                                xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                                version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
                            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        };
        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
        // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                 document.getElementById('login-button').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('logout-button').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```